# Dependency injection into ResourceFilter not working?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jersey, ejb-3.1

I have a bunch of JAX-RS resources that provide an API for a new WebService. In order to understand what's happening, I'd like to store information about each request in a data warehouse. In my mind, this is a perfect example for a cross-cutting concern, which could be implemented by a `ResourceFilter`, right?

So I built a `DataWarehouseService` which is supposed to store stuff in the DB:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class DataWarehouseService {

    public void logApiCall(ContainerRequest cr) {
        // get interesting fields from request, store in DB
        ...
    }
}
```

And here's my filter:

```
public class LoggingResourceFilter implements ResourceFilter {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    @EJB
    DataWarehouseService dwh;

    @Override
    public ContainerRequestFilter getRequestFilter() {

        return new ContainerRequestFilter() {
            @Override
            public ContainerRequest filter(ContainerRequest cr) {
                log.info("Incoming request: "+
                        cr.getHeaderValue("user-agent") +" "+
                        cr.getMethod() +" "+
                        cr.getPath()
                        );

                dwh.logApiRequest(cr);
                return cr;
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public ContainerResponseFilter getResponseFilter() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I inject the filter into my JAX-RS resources via annotation `@ResourceFilters(LoggingResourceFilter.class)` on class-level.

The Filter-injection works fine, when I access one of the JAX-RS resources, the log statement ("Incoming request: ...") gets executed. But immediately afterwards, the call to the injected `DataWarehouseService`'s `dwh.logApiRequest(cr)` fails with a Nullpointer - obviously the injection failed?!

What's the problem here? I thought, `ResourceFilters` are managed and can use CDI. Am I wrong?

All of this runs on Glassfish 3.1.1, Jersey 1.8 is the JAX-RS provider. Would it make a difference if I used `@Inject`?

Comment: A small comment, since `DataWarehouseService` does not implement any business interface `@LocalBean` is redundant. This is only necessary if there is a business interface and you want an additional `no-interface view` on your bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idiot.

Adding a `@Stateless` annotation to the `LoggingResourceFilter` fixed it.

Comment: anything for JAVA 8?