# @inject does not work with stateless EJB

Tags: glassfish, ejb, java-ee-7

Hi I have a very simple example. I created a resource in javaee 7 as follows:

```
@Path("greetings")
public class GreetingsResource {

    @Inject
    Sample s;

    @GET
    public JsonObject greetings(){
        return Json.createObjectBuilder().add("first","1")
                .add("second","2")
                .add("third","3")
                .add("fourth","4")
                .add("helloworld", s.helloWorld())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Sample is the following simple EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class Sample {
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Finally the resource Application class:

```
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class RestConfiguration extends Application {

}
```

I can access the URL: "localhost:8081/jasonandjaxrs/resources/greetings"

The problem is that @Inject gives the following error:

```
1. org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at Injectee(requiredType=sample,parent=GreetingsResource,qualifiers={}),position=-1,optional=false
```

But @EJB seems to work. I am trying to understand why @Inject does not work? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use CDI (means `@Inject`) with this setup. CDI only works with beans managed by the container which is not the case for JAX-RS resource classes (your `GreetingsResource`).

> JAX-RS 2.0 does not support injection of EJBs into JAX-RS components
>   (providers, resources).

If you use `@Inject` in your case the injection is provided by the HK2 dependency injection framework which isn't aware of normal CDI beans. It even shouldn't  work if you use `@EJB`, I don't know why it works, maybe this has to do with Java EE 7.

As it works for you there should be no problem in using `@EJB` here, but there are also some alternative approaches in my response to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21335015/inject-ejb-in-jersey-filter).

**See also:**

- [Inject a EJB into JAX-RS (RESTfull service)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3027834/inject-a-ejb-into-jax-rs-restfull-service)
- [JERSEY-2040  Add support for injection of EJBs into Jersey-managed providers and resources](https://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-2040)

Comment: Thank you @unwichtich. I added stateless to the resource and that at first gave me an error "JAX-RS EJB integration can not be supported". It worked after restarting the server. I am just trying different things. Is there a good tutorial on the different annotations in java ee? Thank you.

Comment: There are mainly technical reference docs about all the annotations but I think this is a good list of examples: http://tomee.apache.org/java-ee-6-annotation-examples.html